# How do I find the distance of a residue coordinate from the solvent accessible surface

Tags: python, biopython

I am trying to use the Biopython residue depth module for finding out the depth of any desired residue from the protein's solvent accessible surface. But it keeps throwing a runtime error. How do i overcome this ?

```
'msms' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LENOVO GAMING-3/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    LIST(myList1)
  File "C:/Users/LENOVO GAMING-3/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 17, in LIST
    surface = get_surface(model)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO GAMING-3\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\Bio\PDB\ResidueDepth.py", line 539, in get_surface
    "Failed to generate surface file using command:\n%s" % make_surface
RuntimeError: Failed to generate surface file using command:
msms -probe_radius 1.5 -if C:\Users\LENOVO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps3luzncx -of C:\Users\LENOVO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzkicezc7 > C:\Users\LENOVO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp34f671ju
```

```
from Bio.PDB import *
from Bio.PDB.ResidueDepth import ResidueDepth
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser
from Bio.PDB.ResidueDepth import min_dist

def LIST(myList1):
   for i in myList1:
      InFile = f'{i}.cif' #.upper()
      structure = MMCIFParser(QUIET=True).get_structure(InFile, f'C:\\Users\\LENOVO GAMING 3\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1\\{i}.cif')
      model = structure[0]
      surface = get_surface(model)
      # rd = ResidueDepth(model)
      # coord = (1.113, 35.393, 9.268)
      dist = min_dist(structure.center_of_mass(geometric=True), surface)
      print(i, structure.header['resolution'], structure.center_of_mass(geometric=True))
      print(dist)


myList1 = ['107l', '108l', '2y7q', '7r2v']
LIST(myList1)
```

Comment: try `from Bio.PDB.ResidueDepth import get_surface` insted of `from Bio.PDB.ResidueDepth import ResidueDepth` in the import section of your code

Comment: did you installed 'msms'  ? did you tried to run it by CLI ?

Comment: i do have msms installed but what to do next ?

Comment: Try to find manual and example of input file and test if the programs wotks. If it is the case start investigating why ghe biopython wrapper doesnt work